# Distance between array rows

Tags: equations, arrays

I am using the `array` environment to create a multiple row bracket expression, as folows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
C(\tau_{k,i})=0.5Q_e\ddot{q}_t^T\ddot{q}_t + 0.5R_e \theta^T \theta & when & t\neq t_v\\
\\
C(\tau_{k,i})=0.5Q_e\ddot{q}_t^T\ddot{q}_t + 0.5R_e \theta^T \theta +    P_{viapoint} & when & t=t_v\\
\\
\quad\quad P_{viapoint}=10^{10}(q_{t}-q_{viapoint})^T(q_{t}-q_{viapoint})

\end{array}\right.  
\label{cost2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which results in something like this:

[image]

However, the vertical spacing between the equations is much greater that the line spacing in the text, and is eating too much space on the paper. Is there a way to reduce the vertical spacing?

Comment: Consider using the `cases` environment (part of the `amsmath` package) for this task.

Comment: Regarding the line spacing: I wonder if you've changed some setting earlier in your document, such as issuing `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}`. Could you post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please?

Comment: You have used `\\ \\ ` so have a blank row between each row of text which is why the spacing is so bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `array` (and `tabular`) environment sets struts in rows. The size of the struts can be reduced by using smaller values than 1 or `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}
\begin{array}{lll}
C(\tau_{k,i})=0.5Q_e\ddot{q}_t^T\ddot{q}_t + 0.5R_e \theta^T \theta
& \text{when} &
t\neq t_v\\
\\
C(\tau_{k,i})=0.5Q_e\ddot{q}_t^T\ddot{q}_t + 0.5R_e \theta^T \theta +
P_{\text{viapoint}} & \text{when} & t=t_v\\
\\
\quad\quad P_{\text{viapoint}}
=10^{10}(q_{t}-q_{\text{viapoint}})^T(q_{t}-q_{\text{viapoint}})
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

You can also take a look at AmSLaTeX (package `amsmath`) that provides many environments for aligned/non-aligned equations and cases structures.